# Magento, Implement Dropdown attribute filtering

Tags: php, magento, attributes, filtering, carousel

So I am new to Magento and still trying to get my get my head wrapped around it. Basically I have multiple dropdowns and am trying to sort products in a carousel. (See attached screenshot)

[image: Product Carousel Filter]

My question is how would I do this with Magento and php. I am fairly familiar with the ajax part. But I am unfamiliar with Magento's methods and would like suggestions from the experts here. What would be the best way to go about this using Magento to do this. I could do this with straight php pretty easy by building a dynamic query with the selected attribute. (I'm sure there are other ways too.) But if anyone can point me in the right direction. It would help me get this project done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this blog post - http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/04/06/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/

Answer (score 0):

I made a dropdown filter category

Around line 50 in app/desing/frontend/your/theme/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
If you replace  all the code inside

For

```
            <!--Filter by Categories-->
            <?php
                $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
                $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
                $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
            ?>
            <div class="block block-list block-categorys">
                <div class="block-content">
                    <ul class="category_sub">
                        <?php if (count($_categories) > 0){ ?>
                        <?php
                            global $index;
                            global $data;
                        ?>
                        <!-- necesary -->
                        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
                            <option  selected ="selected"><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></option>
                            <?php foreach($_categories as $_category){ ?>
                                <option  value="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName();?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

hope you find it useful